# Why mention the "self-conjugate" property in Tannaka duality?

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory

Based on [this Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannaka%E2%80%93Krein_duality#Theorems_of_Tannaka_and_Krein) and [this MathOverflow answer of Qiaochu](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155743/can-one-explain-tannaka-krein-duality-for-a-finite-group-to-a-computer-ho), I believe I've understood Tannaka duality for finite groups. We wish to characterize a finite group $G$ as a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(F)$, where $F:{\rm Rep}_{\Bbb C}(G)\to{\sf Vect}_{\Bbb C}$ is the forgetful functor. One property mentioned in this characterization is that natural transformations are "self-conjugate," but that did not seem to be used at all in the proof of Tannaka for finite groups. Is the property superfluous or does it become necessary when dealing with arbitrary compact groups $G$?

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the important role the regular representation plays in Qiaochu's argument. In order to specify the regular representation as an object of the category without referencing the underlying group you need to use the fact that we have a notion of dual representations.

Comment: @Nate Interesting: without knowing $G$ beforehand we don't a priori know which object in ${\rm Rep}_{\Bbb C}(G)$ is $\Bbb C[G]$. But I think we can specify it without reference to a dual representation: there is a unique object $U$ (up to isomorphism) which represents $F$ (that is, for which $\hom_{\rm Rep}(U,V)\cong FV$ in ${\sf Vect}$ for every rep $V$). As a side note, I've seen a clever proof of the Peter-Weyl decomposition for finite $G$ using the fact $\Bbb C[G]$ represents $F$. But unfortunately I am not sure there is an analogous fact for compact groups to be leveraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The self-conjugate property is unnecessary in the finite case. My guess is that it's used in the compact case because otherwise you would recover something like the corresponding affine algebraic group; e.g. when $G = U(n)$ you would otherwise recover $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't yet set aside time to think about the topological details in Tannaka for compact groups but when I do I'll check if this failure of recovery happens without the self-conjugacy condition.